# OpensCAD pictures of model from command lin

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, openscad

I am trying to take front, top, and side photos of an STL file through the command prompt using OpensCAD.

I tried using:

```
import os
import sys 
import subprocess 
import shutil
import sys

cmd_args = [
    'C:/Program Files/OpenSCAD/openscad.exe',
    'C:/Users/path_to_STL',
    '-o', 
    'C:/Users/path_to_Desktop/front_view.png',
    '-D',
    '--camera=3.3,0.91,-10.7,0,0,0,40',
    '--projection=ortho',
    '--render',
    '--viewall',
    '--autocenter',

]

openscade_command_line_script = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=sys.stdout)
```

However I get a blank picture. I know that the distance and rotation is correct from creating it within the program.

I originally thought it was because the program couldn't open an STL file directly, so I tried opening a .scad file and get the error "Can't parse file 'C:/path_to/bracket2.scad'!

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The `-D` needs a parameter so it's both eating the `--camera=...` and also causing the syntax error as that argument is added to the code.

Comment: @TorstenPaul let me try taking that out.

Comment: @TorstenPaul that soultion worked for me. I did have to write a .scad file to import the STL file, then run this with the converted file to get the images.